# How to fix "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.layers.advanced_activations' "

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to import imageai

```
from imageai.Detection import VideoObjectDetection
```

but get error message below

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.layers.advanced_activations'
```

My tensorflow version       2.9.1,
keras version               2.9.0,
keras-preprocessing version 1.1.2,
image ai version            2.1.5,

I installed the imageai via `pip install imageai-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl` and download from [here](https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/releases/download/2.0.2/imageai-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl).

Comment: keras 2.9.0 no longer has an advanced_activations module. You should try downgrading the package. I tried 2.1.0 and it appears to work

Comment: I tried downgraded keras to 2.1.0 but it's not compatible with tensorflow 2.9.1. May I know what version of tensorflow that is compatible with keras 2.1.0, Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 12):

The following code is an example for calling several types of advanced activation, Try to call it by

```
from keras.layers import ELU, PReLU, LeakyReLU
```

Answer (score 3):

The import works with keras version 2.9.0 as below.

```
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error today. Downgrading my keras to `2.1.0` and tensorflow to `2.2.0` got rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.layers.advanced_activations'
To solve this problem:

Try to install TensorFlow 2.8.2 which is compatible with Keras 2.8.0
pip install tensorflow==2.8.2

Answer (score 0):

Please install `imageai` using this [link](https://imageai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or use below code as you must install few libraries before installing `imageai`.

```
pip install cython pillow>=7.0.0 numpy>=1.18.1 opencv-python>=4.1.2 torch>=1.9.0 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu torchvision>=0.10.0 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu pytest==7.1.3 tqdm==4.64.1 scipy>=1.7.3 matplotlib>=3.4.3 mock==4.0.3

pip install imageai --upgrade
```

then import `VideoObjectDetection` as below:

```
from imageai.Detection import VideoObjectDetection
```